# How do I search property value of some type in XML file and write them to a text file in C++

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010

I have 200 xml files. each one consists of pathways (something like network information). each pathway consists of entities with some attributes. I would like to ask how I can creat a text file for each xml file that contain the only name attributes for all the entities inside this xml file. I have the xml files in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>    
<!DOCTYPE pathway (View Source for full doctype...)> 
- <!--  Creation date: Oct 7, 2014 11:01:31 +0900 (GMT+09:00) --> 
- <pathway name="path:gmx00010" org="gmx" number="00010" title="Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis">
- <entry id="13" name="gmx:100527532 gmx:100775844 gmx:100778363 gmx:100786504 gmx:100792394
  gmx:100795446 gmx:100798677 gmx:100802732 gmx:100815070 gmx:100818383 gmx:100818915 gmx:547751"
  type="gene" >
  </entry>
- <entry id="37" name="gmx:100777399 gmx:100778722 gmx:100782019 gmx:100783726 gmx:100784210 
  gmx:100786773 gmx:100798020 gmx:100798892 gmx:100800699 gmx:100803104 gmx:100808513 
  gmx:100809812 gmx:100811186 gmx:100811501 gmx:100811891 gmx:100816594 gmx:100817701 
  gmx:100819197 gmx:547717" type="gene">
  </entry>
- <entry id="38" name="ko:K01905" type="ortholog">
  </entry>
- <entry id="39" name="ko:K00129" type="ortholog">
  </entry>
```

I want to write a program in visual C++ to create a text file with the same title as the xml file and this text file contains the name attribute values (ex: gmx:100527532 gmx:100775844 gmx:100778363 gmx:100786504 gmx:100792394 gmx:100795446 gmx:100798677 gmx:100802732 gmx:100815070 gmx:100818383 gmx:100818915 gmx:547751) for all the entities of type="gene" and ignore any entity with other types.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. C++ does not contain functions for parsing xml. Pick a library for that (like tinyxml or something) first. Then read its documentation and examples and try to use it and if you have some actual difficulty then ask for help.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. this is the reason why I am asking because I don't know how to start. I spent 3 days trying to find something to start with, so I asked here. Thanks